# Validar checkbox

Tags: php, formularios, checkbox

Tengo un formulario que contiene varias checkbox con distintos valores. Necesito que al darle a enviar en el formulario, los checkboxes que han sido checkeados se guarden en la base de datos que utilizo con phpMyAdmin.

Este es mi html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Formulario</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form">
<form method="POST" id="formulario" name="formulario" role="form">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <br><br>
                    <br><label for="nombre">Su nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a title="Logytel" href="http://logytel.es"><img class="logytel" src="https://i2.wp.com/logytel.es/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/cropped-LOGO_Logytel_2012_R_485C_24x10_8_Blanco.png" alt="Logytel" /></a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="col-md-2">
                    <br><label class="container">Uno
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="1"> <br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>

                    </label>
                    <label class="container">Dos
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="2"> <br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="container">Tres
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="3"> <br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
                    <br><label class="container">Cuatro
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="4"> <br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>

                    </label>
                    <label class="container">Cinco
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="5"> <br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                    <label class="container">Seis
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checks" value="6"> <br>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <br><div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
                      <select>
                        <option name="selects" value="0">Elige uno:</option>
                        <option name="selects" value="1">Uno</option>
                        <option name="selects" value="2">Dos</option>
                        <option name="selects" value="3">Tres</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
        </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
                    <br><div class="custom-select" style="width:200px;">
                      <select>
                        <option name="selects" value="0">Elige uno:</option>
                        <option name="selects" value="1">Uno</option>
                        <option name="selects" value="2">Dos</option>
                        <option name="selects" value="3">Tres</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                    <br><div class="custom-select" style="width:400px; float:left;">
                      <select>
                        <option name="selects" value="0">Elige uno:</option>
                        <option name="selects" value="1">Uno</option>
                        <option name="selects" value="2">Dos</option>
                        <option name="selects" value="3">Tres</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                    <br><div class="custom-select" style="width:400px; float:left;">
                      <select>
                        <option name="selects" value="0">Elige uno:</option>
                        <option name="selects" value="1">Uno</option>
                        <option name="selects" value="2">Dos</option>
                        <option name="selects" value="3">Tres</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
        </div>
        </div>
          </div>
                <br><br>

                <button id="myBtn" class="button" input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="resultado">Enviar</button>

</form>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="mymodal" class="modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <p id="resultado"> Tus datos han sido guardados correctamente.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $('#formulario').submit(function(event) {
            // Obtenemos todos los datos
                var parametros = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
            // Lo enviamos mediante POST
                type: "POST",
            // A la URL
                url: "guardar.php",
            // Le pasamos los datos del formulario
                data: parametros,
                success: function(data) {
        // Abrimos el modal
                $("#mymodal").modal("show");
            // Mostramos el resultado de la URL
                $('#resultado').html(data);
            // Reseteamos el formulario
                document.getElementById("formulario").reset();
            }
        $("#mymodal").modal("hide");
            });


        // Prevenimos que el botón submit recargue la página
            event.preventDefault();
        });
            </script>

        <script>
            var x, i, j, selElmnt, a, b, c;
            /*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
            x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
            /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
            a = document.createElement("DIV");
            a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
            a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
            x[i].appendChild(a);
            /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
            b = document.createElement("DIV");
            b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
            for (j = 1; j < selElmnt.length; j++) {
                /*for each option in the original select element,
                create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
                c = document.createElement("DIV");
                c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
                c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
                    and the selected item:*/
                    var y, i, k, s, h;
                    s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
                    h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
                for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                    if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
                        s.selectedIndex = i;
                            h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
                            y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
                            for (k = 0; k < y.length; k++) {
                            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
                            }
                                this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    h.click();
                    });
                b.appendChild(c);
            }
            x[i].appendChild(b);
            a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
                and open/close the current select box:*/
                e.stopPropagation();
                closeAllSelect(this);
                this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
                this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
                });
            }
            function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
            /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
            except the current select box:*/
            var x, y, i, arrNo = [];
            x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
            y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
            for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
                    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
                    arrNo.push(i)
                    } else {
                    y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
                    }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
                x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
                }
            }
        }
        /*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
        then close all select boxes:*/
        document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
        </script>
```

Este el PHP que guarda los datos enviados del formulario:

```
<?php
    //conectamos Con el servidor
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $db="prueba";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die ("Problemas al conectar");
    mysqli_select_db($con,$db) or die ("Problemas al conectar con la base de datos");

    //recuperar las variables
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $checks=$_POST['checks'];

    //Hacer secuencia sql
    $sql="INSERT INTO datos (nombre, checks) VALUES ('{$nombre}','{$checks}')";

    //ejecutamos la sentencia de sql
    $ejecutar=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    //verificamos la ejecucion
    if(!$ejecutar){

        echo"Hubo Algun Error {msqli_error($conn)}";

    }else{
        echo"Datos Guardados Correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";
    }
?>
```

Y este el php que muestra los datos en la tabla de la bd

```
<?php 

    //hacemos la conexion para la base de datos:
    $con= mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

    //verificamos la conexion
    if(!$con){

        echo"No Se Encontro El Servidor";

    }else{

        $db= mysqli_select_db('prueba'); //nombre bbdd
    //verificamos la base de datos
        if(!$db){

            echo"No Se Encontro La Base De Datos";

        }
    }
    //Se Hace la sentencia sql:
    $sql="SELECT * FROM datos"; //nombre tabla

    //ejecutamos la sentencia de slq:
    $ejecutar=mysqli_query($sql);

    //traemos todos los valores en un array:
    $datos=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar);

    //imprimimos los datos de manera dinamica
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo"<tr>";
    echo "<th align='center'><b>Nombre</th>";
    echo "<th align='center'><b>Checks</th>";
    echo"</tr>";
    for($i=0; $i<$datos; $i++){
        echo"<tr><td>$datos[0]</td>";
        echo"<td>$datos[1]</td>";
        echo"<td>$datos[2]</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
        $datos=mysqli_fetch_array($ejecutar);
    }
    echo"</table>";
?>
```

He estado buscando por dintintas páginas, probando códigos y nada. En este ejemplo hay uno de ellos metido, no sé si lo formulé mal, si llevaba comas o si no, igual lo probé y tampoco funcionaba, y aparte, antes me registraba los datos del nombre que era lo único que tenía, funcionaba bien, vale, pero cuando metí los checkbox, dejó de funcionar y ahora no me registra nada. Así que algo tiene que estar fallando y no encuentro el qué es.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101358/discussion-on-question-by-lucia-validar-checkbox).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el código Javascript tienes el `hide` fuera de bloque, lo cual producirá error. Ese bloque podría quedar así:

```
    <script>
        $('#formulario').submit(function(event) {
        // Obtenemos todos los datos
            var parametros = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
        // Lo enviamos mediante POST
            type: "POST",
        // A la URL
            url: "guardar.php",
        // Le pasamos los datos del formulario
            data: parametros,
            success: function(data) {
    // Abrimos el modal
            $("#mymodal").modal("show");
        // Mostramos el resultado de la URL
            $('#resultado').html(data);
        // Reseteamos el formulario
            document.getElementById("formulario").reset();
            $("#mymodal").modal("hide");

        }
        });

    // Prevenimos que el botón submit recargue la página
        event.preventDefault();
    });
        </script>
```

Además no estás usando el formulario para serializar los elementos, porque ahí `this` representa el botón, no el formulario. deberías crear la variable `parametros` así:

```
            var parametros = $("#formulario").serialize();
```

En cuanto al código PHP, le falta algunos controles y hay cosas de más.

Prueba el código de esta manera. Si hay algún error lo dirá:

```
<?php
    //conectamos Con el servidor
    $host="localhost";
    $user="root";
    $pass="";
    $db="prueba";

    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die ("Problemas al conectar");

    //recuperar las variables
    $nombre=!empty($_POST['nombre']) ? $_POST['nombre'] : NULL;
    $checks=!empty($_POST['checks']) ? $_POST['checks'] : NULL;

    if ($nombre && $checks) {
        //Hacer secuencia sql
        $sql="INSERT INTO datos (nombre, checks) VALUES ('{$nombre}','{$checks}')";

        //ejecutamos la sentencia de sql y verificamos al mismo tiempo
        if ( $ejecutar=mysqli_query($con,$sql) ) {
            $msg="Datos Guardados Correctamente<br><a href='index.html'>Volver</a>";
        }else{
            $msg="Hubo Algun Error {msyqli_error($con)}";
        }
    }else{
        $msg="No se mandaron los datos desde el formulario";
    }
    echo $msg;
?>
```